# creating region of interest (ROI) in opencv Java

Tags: java, c#, opencv

I have trying to create a region of interest in Opencv today but have not been successful at all, my project is about a traffic counter app, I am tracking vehicles based on their Blobs, to reduce processing time I set Minimum and maxmimum blob but thats not enough, I want to create a Region of interest where Opencv will be doing all processing, I tried detecting the road but It was not giving me the desired results, here is the code I implemented

```
   private static void segmentation(Mat src) {
       Mat matGray = src.clone();
         matEdges = new Mat(matGray.height(), matGray.width(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
       //    Imgproc.cvtColor(matGray, matGray, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB, 0);
         matGray.submat(0, matGray.height(), (2 * matGray.width()) / 3, matGray.width()).copyTo(matEdges.submat(0, matGray.height(), (2 * matGray.width()) / 3, matGray.width()));
         Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(matEdges, matEdges, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 3, -1.5);
         Imgproc.erode(matEdges, matEdges, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(2, 2)));

    }


  private static void detectLane(Mat src) {

       segmentation(src);
        //Matrix of detected lines
        Mat lines = new Mat();
        Line leftLane = new Line(0, src.height(), src.width(), 0);
        Line rightLane = new Line(src.width(), src.height(), 0, 0);
        //Straight line detection
        Imgproc.HoughLines(matEdges, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, 70);
        double maxLaneY = src.height();
        boolean isLeftHorizontal = true;
        boolean isRightHorizontal = true;
        double midLaneX = src.width() / 2;
        double minLaneX = 0;
        double maxLaneX = src.width();
        double minLeftLaneY = 3 * src.height() / 4;
        double minRightLaneY = 3 * src.height() / 4;

        //Get rho and theta values for every line and convert it to cartesian space
        for (int j = 0; j < lines.cols(); j++) {
            double[] vec = lines.get(0, j);
            double rho = vec[0],
                    theta = vec[1];

            //Vertical-ish lines conversion
            if ((theta < Math.PI / 4 || theta > 3 * Math.PI / 4)) {

                double topX = rho / Math.cos(theta);
                double bottomX = (rho - src.width() * Math.sin(theta)) / Math.cos(theta);

                if (minLaneX < bottomX && bottomX <= midLaneX) {
                    minLaneX = bottomX;
                    leftLane.setLine(bottomX, topX, src.width(), 0);
                    isLeftHorizontal = false;
                }
                if (midLaneX < bottomX && bottomX < maxLaneX) {
                    maxLaneX = bottomX;
                    rightLane.setLine(bottomX, topX, src.width(), 0);
                    isRightHorizontal = false;
                }
            } 
            //Horizontal-ish lines conversion
            else {

                double leftY = rho / Math.sin(theta);
                double rightY = (rho - src.width() * Math.cos(theta)) / Math.sin(theta);

                if (leftY > minLeftLaneY && leftY < maxLaneY && isLeftHorizontal) {
                    minLeftLaneY = leftY;
                    leftLane.setLine(0, src.width(), leftY, rightY);
                }
                if (rightY > minRightLaneY && rightY < maxLaneY && isRightHorizontal) {
                    minRightLaneY = rightY;
                    rightLane.setLine(src.width(), 0, rightY, leftY);
                }
            }

        }

        //Get the horizon
        Point i = Line.getIntersectionPoint(leftLane, rightLane);

        if (i != null && i.x > 0 && i.x < src.width() && i.y > 0 && i.y < src.height()) {
            //Draw the lines with horizon
           Imgproc.line(src, leftLane.getStart(), i, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
           Imgproc.line(src, rightLane.getStart(), i, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
        } else {
            //Draw the lines without horizon
            Imgproc.line(src, leftLane.getStart(), leftLane.getEnd(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
            Imgproc.line(src, rightLane.getStart(), rightLane.getEnd(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
        }

        //Draw segmentation borders
        //drawBordersToMRgba();

        //Cleanup
        System.err.println("lines:" + lines.cols());
        lines.release();
        lines = null;
    }
```

Here are the My Code Results but I want it to look like Image 2

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

If my idea cannot work at least you could help me on how I can pick mat points by clicking on the Image in the video then create a rectangle from those points and use it as ROI, I have tried searching online but unfortunately I have not been successful, languages like `C#` have methods like `Mat.setRoi()` but not in Java

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue, `JavaFX`(as well as Swing) can listen to mouse activities, so here is what I do

I attach a mouse event listener to the root view and get all points, that is all 4 points
            root.setOnKeyPressed(eventHandler);

```
    imageView.setOnMousePressed(event -> {

        mousePosition.x = event.getX();
        mousePosition.y = event.getY();
```

Then I check if the mouse evens were within my window

```
        if (mousePosition.inside(window.getImageArea()))
        {
            //if true the draw
        }

    });
```